# Knockout unable to parse binding internal method

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I might be missing something really simple but can anyone point out where i'm doing wrong here?

many thanks in advance.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: agencies">
    <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
    <div data-bind="text:email"></div>
    <button data-bind="click: removeAgency">remove</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var agency = [{
        name : ko.observable('a'),
        email : ko.observable('b')
    }, {
        name: ko.observable('c'),
        email: ko.observable('d')
    }];

    var vm = {
        agencies: ko.observableArray(agency),
        removeAgency: function(agency) {
            this.agencies.remove(agency);
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

this is the error i get: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: removeAgency is not defined;
Bindings value: click: removeAgency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are binding to an agency in that html, but your method is on your viewmodel. Try something like:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.removeAgency">remove</button>
```

You might need to re-jig your vm to get the scope correct:

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.agencies = ko.observableArray(agency),
    self.removeAgency = function(agency) {
        self.agencies.remove(agency);
    }
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
```

I still get confused at times with scope, I have to admit, but give this a try and see what happens.

Comment: Not something like that, but exactly that is what you need :)

Comment: thanks for quick reply @Paul. now it says : Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/marko4286/7RDc3/2034/
```

Read documentation `http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html`